# MySQL , PHP : Hide specific Value from table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a ' Show Online user' script where the script show everybody who is online.
Now i want to remve the entry which matches the session user name i.e "if (Online user = Session User name ) then do not display it , just like on facebook.com chat where your friends id is shown and not your own Id 
my code is as follows :

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","12345");
    mysql_select_db("accounts");
    $user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online * WHERE ($chat<>$user)");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $chat=$row["emp_name"];
      $chlk = ("<a href=javascript:void(0) onclick=javascript:chatWith('$chat')>$chat</a>");
      $chs = ("<a>$chat</a>");
      if ($chat <> $user) {
      echo $chlk;
      }
      else {
      echo $chs;
      }
   echo $chlk;
}
?>
```

I am getting the following error :

`Notice: Undefined variable: chat in localhost/accounts/removeuser.php on line 7`

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given localhost/accounts/removeuser.php on line 9
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: make sure `$result` does not have boolean....share code for `$result`

Comment: I think your problem is in "removeuser.php" line 9...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction in query.

```
"SELECT * FROM online WHERE ($chat<>$user)"
```

**OR**

**Replace** `$chat` in query with your table `field` name.

there is extra * before WHERE that is invalid.

and `$chat` is not defined in `query`.

Comment: i tried the correction but the script still gives the same error , 
could you recommend a script where all users are show except the user which is viewing the list ?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM online WHERE username != '".$_SESSION['loggedInUser']."'"`

Comment: thanx i got it , but not the way you told , i used not like ..
`    SELECT * FROM online WHERE emp_name NOT LIKE '%$user%'"`

Comment: @AadityaChakravarty well even `emp_name != '$user'"` also work..because if you have aaditya and aadit in table then both not selected so use != is best to eliminate exact user.

Answer (score 0):

`<>` is not PHP as far as I know. You need to use `!==`.

*(and probably read up on some PHP basics...)*